# is there a python-version specific "#pragma nocover" available for python coverage tool?

Tags: python, coverage.py

Using python coverage.py, i'd love to do something like:

```
if six.PY3:
    from functools import lru_cache
else:
    from .lru_cache_local imoprt lru_cache
```

and then, using tox, not have my python2 specific code count against my coverage report.... is there anything like

```
# pragma: nocover_py2

# pragma: nocover_py3
```

available?

thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The .coveragerc file will expand environment variables, so you can do:

```
[report]
exclude_lines =
    pragma: no cover
    pragma: nocover_${PRAGMA_VERSION}
```

Then run coverage.py like this:

```
PRAGMA_VERSION=py2 coverage report
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [provide your own "no cover" lines](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/4.5.4/excluding.html#advanced-exclusion) via the configuration file.

```
# py2.coveragerc
[report]
exclude_lines =
    pragma: no cover
    pragma: nocover_py2
```

Then you could choose whether to use the Python 2 config file, or the Python 3 config file via [the `--rcfile` option](http://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/4.5.4/config.html#configuration-files).

```
coverage2 run --rcfile=py2.coveragerc ...
coverage2 report --rcfile=py2.coveragerc ...

coverage3 run --rcfile=py3.coveragerc ...
coverage3 report --rcfile=py3.coveragerc ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than exclude lines, you're better off measuring the coverage of both python 2 and python 3, and then combining them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for inspiration.... my solution ended up looking like this.  It would have been nice to generalize to just .py2 and .py3, but tox doesn't seem to provide a large vocabulary of execution environment params :(.

**.coveragerc_py27**

```
...
[report]
exclude_lines =
      pragma: nocover
      pragma: py2_nocover
....
```

**.coveragerc_py34**

```
...
[run]
omit = *_py2.py

[report]
exclude_lines =
      pragma: nocover
      pragma: py3_nocover
....
```

**tox.ini**

```
...
[testenv]
commands = pytest \
    --cov-config .coveragerc_{envname} \
    ...
```